# Install gcc49 via homebrew failed

Tags: gcc, terminal, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install gcc49 via homebrew.

I give a command like:

```
brew install gcc49
```

but it is stuck at

```
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
==> make bootstrap
```

Comment: Building GCC from source takes a very long time.  How long as it been in this state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes quite sometime. I did not time it per se - but I left it working for around 1.5 hours before I returned to the window - then it was done. So timewise anything between 15 min and 1.5hrs I'd say. If you are running your terminal in a window and text keeps changing in the header it's all good. Just don't cancel it - let it do it's work. If you have other things to do, get those done first; if not - go on youtube :)

Comment: From my recent install: ==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4: 1009 files, 108M, built in 25.1 minutes

Answer (score 0):

It takes time. On my computer it takes about 1 hour. so just be patient and let it works. Even sometimes the header of Terminal does not change and stop on "cc1plus". Don't cancel it and do other thing until it will be done :)

Comment: On my system: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.8.3_1: 1045 files, 177M, built in 89.4 minutes.

Comment: `$ /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2: 1156 files, 203M, built in 49.6 minutes`